# Proof of extended version of non-random "almost supermartingale"

Tags: real-analysis, nonlinear-optimization, convex-analysis, martingales, global-optimization

In this [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/412729/can-we-invoke-almost-supermartingale-theorem-for-deterministic-sequences/412747#412747), a non-random version of "almost supermartingale" theorem is proved.

Here, I would like to extend/apply the non-random version to the slightly different situation. I wonder whether the theorem holds under this extended version case, does it?

Let me define some non-negative variables

\begin{align}
v_k &:= \alpha_k\|x_k - x^\star \|_2^2 \\
t_k &:= \gamma_k \|x_k - x_{k-1} \|_2^2
\end{align}
where $\alpha_k, \gamma_k \in \mathbb{R}_{+}$.

*ADDENDUM1*: $\{x_k \!\in \mathbb{R}^d\!\}$ are the sequences generated by a convex optimization algorithm and $x^{\star} \!\in \mathbb{R}^d$ is an optimal solution.

*ADDENDUM2*: {Both $\alpha_k$ and $\gamma_k$ are monotonically decreasing over increasing $k$, i.e., $\alpha_{k+1} \leq \alpha_{k}$ and $\gamma_{k+1} \leq \gamma_{k}$ forall $k$. The supremum of both $\{\alpha_k\}$ and  $\{ \gamma_k\}$ is less than infinity.}}

Let $\beta_k \geq 0$, which satisfy $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \beta_k < \infty$. Also, let $\{s_k\}$ be another non-negative variable.

Assume
\begin{align}
v_{k+1} + t_{k+1} \leq \left( 1 + \beta_k \right) v_{k} + t_{k} - s_k \tag{$\clubsuit$},
\end{align}

**Question**:
Then, can we extend or/and apply non-random version of "almost supermartingale" theorem (or some other theorem?) to $(\clubsuit)$ such that
\begin{align}
v_k &\rightarrow v^{\infty} \ \text{or} \ x_k \rightarrow x^{\star} ?
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
t_k &\rightarrow 0 ?
\end{align}

Comment: With $\alpha_k$ and $\gamma_k$ being unspecified nonnegative real numbers, you have $v_k$ and $t_k$ as unspecified nonnegative real numbers, except that they are related by ($\clubsuit$). So, hardly anything can be said about $v_k$ and $t_k$. Some additional conditions on $\alpha_k$ and $\gamma_k$ may be useful.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Thank you very much for your reply. I am sorry for missing out some details on $\alpha_k$ and $\gamma_k$. 
I can say that $\alpha_k$ and $\gamma_k$ is monotonically decreasing over increasing $k$, i.e., $\alpha_{k+1} \leq \alpha_{k}$ and $\gamma_{k+1} \leq \gamma_{k}$. The supremum of both $\{\alpha_k\}$ and  $\{ \gamma_k\}$ is less than infinity. Please let me know what additional assumption would be needed on $\alpha_k$ and $\gamma_k$.

Comment: Also, what are $x_k$, $x^*$, $\|\cdot\|$?

Comment: Oops,  $\{x_k\}$ are the sequences generated by a convex optimization algorithm  and $x^{*}$ is an optimal solution. We can assume Euclidean norm $\| \cdot \|_2$. Is that enough information or am I still goofing up?

Comment: So, a priori $(x_k)$ can be any sequence in $\mathbb R^d$ (?) and $x^*$ any vector  in $\mathbb R^d$, right?

Comment: That is correct. Sorry for not being clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}$The answer to each of your three questions is no.

Indeed, suppose that $\alpha_k=\gamma_k=1$ and $\beta_k=s_k=0$ for all $k$. Suppose that the dimension $d$ is $1$ (then the counterexample presented below can be obviously "imbedded" into $\R^d$ for any natural $d$).

Let $x^\star:=0$. Let
\begin{equation}
    (x_0, x_1, x_2, x_3):=(2-\sqrt{5},-1,\sqrt{5}-2,1)
\end{equation}
and then let
\begin{equation}
    x_k:=x_{k-4}
\end{equation}
for natural $k\ge4$, so that the sequence $(x_k)_{k\ge0}$ is periodic with period $4$.
Hence, the sequences $(v_k)_{k\ge0}=(x_k^2)_{k\ge0}$ and $(t_k)_{k\ge1}=((x_k-x_{k-1})^2)_{k\ge1}$ are also periodic with period $4$, with
\begin{equation}
    (v_1, v_2, v_3,v_4)=(v_1, v_0, v_1,v_0), 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    (t_1, t_2, t_3,t_4)=(t_1,t_0, t_1,t_0),
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    v_0=9 - 4\sqrt5,\quad v_1=1,\quad t_0:=6-2\sqrt5,\quad t_1=14 - 6\sqrt5, 
\end{equation}
so that $   v_1+t_1=v_0+t_0$ and hence
\begin{equation}
    v_{k+1} + t_{k+1}=v_k+t_k \tag{$\clubsuit\clubsuit$}
\end{equation}
for all natural $k$. So, recalling that $\beta_k=s_k=0$ for all $k$, we see that your condition ($\clubsuit$) holds.

However, since each of the sequences $(v_k)_{k\ge0}$, $(x_k)_{k\ge0}$, and $(t_k)_{k\ge1}$ is non-constant and periodic, we see that none of the conditions $v_k\to v^{\infty}$, $x_k \to x^{\star}$, $t_k\to0$ holds.

*Remark:* If we want the sequence $(v_k)_{k\ge0}$ to be alternating between two different values and if we want $(\clubsuit\clubsuit)$ to hold for all natural $k$, then
the sequence $(x_k)_{k\ge0}$ in the above example is uniquely determined up to rescaling (that is, replacing the sequence $(x_k)_{k\ge0}$ by the rescaled sequence $(cx_k)_{k\ge0}$ for some nonzero real $c$) and/or the swapping $x_{2j}$ with $x_{2j+1}$ for all $j=0,1,\dots$, to get the sequence $(x_1,x_0,x_3,x_2,\dots)$.

---

The picture below shows the oscillatory behavior of the periodic sequence
$$
\begin{aligned}
(x_k)_{k\ge0}&=(x_0, x_1, x_2, x_3, x_0, x_1, x_2, x_3,\dots) \\ 
&=(x_0, x_1, -x_0, -x_1, x_0, x_1, -x_0, -x_1,\dots)\,:
\end{aligned}
$$

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, Iosif! I see your point, but now I realized that the initialization of $x_0$ should be 'appropriate'. Additionally, most of the papers have proved the convergence of their optimization algorithms using such type of inequalities after summing it to infinity. Then, they argue about "cluster point"...

Comment: See, example http://www.optimization-online.org/DB_FILE/2017/09/6228.pdf (page 12), https://arxiv.org/pdf/1504.01032.pdf on page 29 equation (A.3). What am I missing?

Comment: @user550103 : I certainly understand your frustration, especially after sacrificing 100 points of your reputation but getting a no-no-no answer. It was to be expected that some condition(s) are missing in your post. In my comments to your post, I did try (thrice) to help you add obviously missing conditions. After that, I spent a substantial amount of time to come up with the above answer, which points out to the neeed in some further, less obviously missing conditions. As such, this answer to your questions is complete. So, let us have a closure here.

Comment: Previous comment continued: After that, you may want to further research literature and come up with working additional conditions.

Comment: I greatly appreciate your time and input, Iosif! I will accept your answer. Thank you very much. I certainly need to continue researching literature.

Comment: @user550103 : I hope this answer can help you find conditions appropriate to your problem to eliminate the oscillatory behavior. I have added a remark that this counterexample is essentially unique, which also might be of help.

Comment: Ineed Iosif. This counter example is quite illuminating. In fact, I have observed such oscillatory behaviour numerically under some parameter settings. However, the sequences seem to converge eventually. Most importantly, these papers do not discuss about such an oscillatory behaviour. Additionally, I fail to find an important condition/assumption in these papers that can avoid such a behaviour. Perhaps someday I will figure out or never.

Comment: @user550103 : The conditions in those papers probably do not **explicitly** exclude such oscillations. However, perhaps you can check which of those conditions fail to hold in the above counterexample. Then you can add such conditions or similar ones, hopefully to rule out oscillations. This may be a specific way to utilize the counterexample.

Comment: Very nice picture, Iosif. Thank you very much. I truly respect your efforts. You have a good point. I will ponder over.