# Proof of yet another extension of deterministic variant of "(Almost) Supermartingale" convergence theorem

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, martingales

In this [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/412729/can-we-invoke-almost-supermartingale-theorem-for-deterministic-sequences), there is a proof for deterministic version of "Almost Supermartingale"

**Question: Can we extend [[1](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/412729/can-we-invoke-almost-supermartingale-theorem-for-deterministic-sequences)] as following? If yes, can we prove it?**

> Let the non-negative sequences be $\{V_1^k\}$, $\{V_2^k\}$, $\{S_{1,2}^k\}$, and $\{ U_{1,2}^k \}$ for $k=0,1,2,\ldots$. Let $\alpha_0, \alpha_1, \ldots$ and $\beta_0, \beta_1, \ldots$ be non-negative scalars satisfying $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \alpha_k < \infty$ and $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \beta_k < \infty$. Assume
> $$V_1^{k+1} + V_2^{k+1} \leq \left( 1 + \alpha_k \right) V_1^k + \left( 1 + \beta_k \right) V_2^k - S_{1,2}^k + U_{1,2}^k$$
> and
> $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty U_{1,2}^i < \infty.$$
> Then,
>
> 1. $V_1^k \rightarrow V_1^\infty$
> 2. $V_2^k \rightarrow V_2^\infty$
> 3. $\sum_{k=0}^\infty S_{1,2}^k < \infty$.

P.S.: Question: Is there any "name" of such convergence theorem in [[1](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/412729/can-we-invoke-almost-supermartingale-theorem-for-deterministic-sequences)] besides stating non-random version of (almost) supermartingale?

---

ATTEMPT:

We can split the above inequality
\begin{align}
V_1^{k+1}  \leq \left( 1 + \alpha_k \right) V_1^k - {\color{red}{\frac{1}{2}}}S_{1,2}^k + {\color{red}{\frac{1}{2}}}U_{1,2}^k \tag{1}
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
V_2^{k+1}  \leq \left( 1 + \beta_k \right) V_2^k - {\color{red}{\frac{1}{2}}}S_{1,2}^k + {\color{red}{\frac{1}{2}}}U_{1,2}^k. \tag{2}
\end{align}

From [[1](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/412729/can-we-invoke-almost-supermartingale-theorem-for-deterministic-sequences)], we know that both $(1)$ and $(2)$ can have $V_1^k \to V_1^\infty$ and $V_2^k \to V_2^\infty$. Also, $\sum_{k=0}^\infty S_{1,2}^k < \infty$ follows directly from both $(1)$ and $(2)$.

**Does this above approach make sense?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. E.g., for $j=1,2$ and $k=0,1,\dots$, take  $V_j^k=2+(-1)^{j+k}$, $S_{1,2}^k=0$, $U_{1,2}^k=0$, $\alpha_k=0$, and $\beta_k=0$.

Comment: Thank you, Iosif! That is true.

Comment: Any possibility to prove that with some (obvious) assumption?

Comment: @user550103 : I think it might be of help if you disclose specifics of what you are actually trying to accomplish as the end result, instead of soliciting additional conditions, which may well turn out to be not applicable in your setting.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply as I was away. 

I am trying to extend and/or relate supermartingale convergence theorem with "quasi-Fejér" monotonicity (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1206.5705.pdf). 

I am still at basic level. But my gut feelings say that there can be some relation and synergy among these two approaches.

Comment: Let us focus on finite-dimensional spaces, for instance Euclidean space. Let $C$ be a nonempty closed subset of the Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $(x_k)_{k\geq0}$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Additionally, let $\{W_k\}$ be a positive definite matrix such that $W_{k+1} \preceq \left(1+\alpha_k\right)W_{k}$, where $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \alpha_k < \infty$.  [1/2]

Comment: Assume, for all $z \in C$ and $k \geq 0$, $\| x_{k+1} - z \|_{W_{k+1}} \leq \left(1+\alpha_k\right)\| x_{k} - z \|_{W_{k}} + \epsilon_k$, where  $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \epsilon_k < \infty$, and every sequential cluster point of $(x_k)_{k\geq0}$ belongs to $C$. Then, $(x_k)_{k\geq0}$ converges to an element in $C$. [2/2]

Comment: So, connecting it with deterministic supermartingale, we can say $v_{k+1} \equiv \| x_{k+1} - z \|_{W_{k+1}}$ and $u_k \equiv \epsilon_k$. Then one can see some relation, or!? As usual, I might make mistake as I see things from basic level...

Comment: Now, I wanted to change $W_{k+1} \preceq \left(1+\alpha_k\right)W_{k}$ to $W_{k+1} \preceq W_{k} \!+\! P_{k} $, where $P_k$ is a positive semidefinite matrix. But then I wonder, does the convergence still hold in this case?

Comment: Since it's a long comment, I have created a related question herein https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4364187/potential-extension-of-variable-metric-quasi-fej%c3%a9r-monotone-interesting-converg . Would be grateful to receive your comments/answers because you come up with very interesting counterexamples. :)

Comment: @user550103 : I am not really active on Math SE. Yet, in this case I did give an answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, Iosif! You are very kind and helpful. I am trying to learn so much from you.